# CSOM returns 403 Forbidden when checking site collection

Tags: csom, adfs, credentials, console-application, 403

I am creating a console application to create Subsite's, lists, list items etc. I have a simple function that checks if a `SiteCollection` exists and am met with a `403 Forbidden` error when calling the `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()` function.

Example Code:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
     Web web = ctx.Web;
     ctx.Load(web);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //403 Error
}
```

So I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751995/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden-error) thread which detailed passing `NetworkCredential` object to the context. So I changed my code to:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
     Web web = ctx.Web;
     ctx.Load(web);
     ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "pass", "domain");
     ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //Still 403's
}
```

It still 403's and I have gone back to verify the accounts credentials and permissions across the site that I am attempting to access.

Is there an issue with my code or is it something else? Can `CSOM` go cross server?

**UPDATE**

The code above works on a server with `Active Directory`, but not a server utilizing `ADFS`. `ADFS` possibly blocking this call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to add this here. Unfortunately the suggested answers of adding `NetworkCredential` did not work. I instead switched from using `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` dll to the `Microsoft.SharePoint` library. Everything works now except with the caveat of course that my application now has to be run on a SharePoint server.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting c`tx.Credentials` before.

Other than that, double check your user/pwd/domain

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
     ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "pass", "domain");
     Web web = ctx.Web;
     ctx.Load(web);
     ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //Still 403's
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with the same issue, I looked at the SharePoint Office PNP core samples, and tried to login using the default browser login, you can try the below sample I got working

```
string myAdfsSharePoint= "https://abc.myTenant.com/sites/abc";
OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager am = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
SP.ClientContext ctx = am.GetWebLoginClientContext(myAdfsSharePoint);
```

Also, make sure to have the default browser signed in, Since I had to prepare an Offline utility for my Client, I was allowed to !
I had to include this DLL from Github [OfficeCorePnp](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/tree/master/Samples/Tenant.Migration/Modules/2017/March/SharePointPnPPowerShell2013/Modules/SharePointPnPPowerShell2013) Samples